# UIView created by touchesBegin() doesn't removed because touchesEnded() never get called when user removed the finger from the iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uiview, uitouch

Update[11/1/2018]:

I try to test the code step by step and found that:

- The method *touchesEnded* was never called for the leftover UIView.
- Same for the method *touchesCancelled*

---

I am following the Apple Documentation on implementing a multitouch app.

The url is : 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view/implementing_a_multitouch_app

I am using the 4 methods:
 - touchesBegan(*:with:),
 - touchesMoved(*:with:),
 - touchesEnded(*:with:),
 - touchesCancelled(*:with:)

to create a UIView on the touching location when touchesBegan is called. Update the UIView location when touchesMoved is called. And finally, remove the UIView when touchesEnded and touchedCancelled is called.

The problem is when I am tapping really fast on the screen, the UIView doesn't remove from the superview. The code is basically the same as the code provided in the URL with different graphics. I add another view which offset a little bit from the touch location to have a better look on the touch point.

[Example of the leftover UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP8Ce.jpg)

[Another Image, same code as the comment below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1peY.jpg)

I don't understand what's wrong and why is this happening. I suspect that touchesEnded() was never called but I don't know why. And I would like to ask is there any method to prevent this from happening (no leftover UIView)?

I am using XCode Version 9.2 (9C40b) and iPad Air 2.
I have try the app on different iPad model and same thing happen.

Part of the codes:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        createViewForTouch(touch: touch)
    }
}

func createViewForTouch( touch : UITouch ) {
    let newView = TouchSpotView() //TouchSportView is a custom UIView
    newView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    newView.center = touch.location(in: self)

    // Add the view and animate it to a new size.
    addSubview(newView)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        newView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    // Save the views internally
    touchViews[touch] = newView //touchViews is a dict, i.e. touchView[UITouch:TouchSportView]
}

func removeViewForTouch (touch : UITouch ) {
    if let view = touchViews[touch] {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        touchViews.removeValue(forKey: touch)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        removeViewForTouch(touch: touch)
    }
}
```

For the full code, please see the attached URL for apple documentation.

Many thanks for your generous help!!!!

Comment: Can you should us your code? The UIView.

Comment: Most likely, you need to create an animation starting with touchesBegan.

Comment: The code is the same as the one in the apple documentation

Comment: And yes I delete the animation code, let me try what happens if I add back the animation.

Comment: Doesn't help at all

Comment: Does this happen only on an actual device or using the simulator as well?  I ask because I took your code and it works in the simulator.  I had to add code for the TouchSpotView and the touchesView so can you also show how those are setup.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth It happens to the actual device. It is a multitouch app so I didn't test it on the simulator.
For the TouchSpotView and touchesView, please refer to the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view/implementing_a_multitouch_app).

Comment: @TaiMing can you test it on iphone?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ yes,  same thing happens.

Comment: @TaiMing One last thing that I can try - I have added a link to a GitHub project with a minimal example that should work without problems (multiTouch-wise). Try to pull it and run it. If that doesn't work, then I really have no idea how to solve it (I cannot reproduce your problem).

Comment: @MilanNosáľ Thanks, Man. But it doesn't work. The problems are touch cancelled and ended were never called. I have checked the responder chain (UIView - ViewController - UIWindow - AppDelegate) and no one handles the event. My current solution is to check the total number of touch by event?.allTouches as a checking.

Answer (score 1):

Tried following code (copy pasted from the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/handling_touches_in_your_view/implementing_a_multitouch_app) you provided) and it works perfectly both on actual device and simulator:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        view = TouchableView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

class TouchableView: UIView {
    var touchViews = [UITouch:TouchSpotView]()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            createViewForTouch(touch: touch)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let view = viewForTouch(touch: touch)
            // Move the view to the new location.
            let newLocation = touch.location(in: self)
            view?.center = newLocation
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            removeViewForTouch(touch: touch)
        }
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            removeViewForTouch(touch: touch)
        }
    }

    func createViewForTouch( touch : UITouch ) {
        let newView = TouchSpotView()
        newView.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        newView.center = touch.location(in: self)

        // Add the view and animate it to a new size.
        addSubview(newView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            newView.bounds.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        }

        // Save the views internally
        touchViews[touch] = newView
    }

    func viewForTouch (touch : UITouch) -> TouchSpotView? {
        return touchViews[touch]
    }

    func removeViewForTouch (touch : UITouch ) {
        if let view = touchViews[touch] {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
            touchViews.removeValue(forKey: touch)
        }
    }
}

class TouchSpotView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // Update the corner radius when the bounds change.
    override var bounds: CGRect {
        get { return super.bounds }
        set(newBounds) {
            super.bounds = newBounds
            layer.cornerRadius = newBounds.size.width / 2.0
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you are doing something more with it, add that additional code to the question, or if you removed something from the code, let us know. Otherwise, it should work.

**EDIT**

For completeness I am including a [GitHub link](https://github.com/MilanNosal/MultiTouchTest) to a minimal project, that works for me.

Comment: I build another Xcode project and copy and paste the code into the view controller. The same thing happens when I move my finger really really fast.
I had also attached another image to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding why touchesCancelled and touchesEnded were not called, using event?.allTouches method to check all touch which UITouch is not being handled.